# The negative of a vector field and its flow

Tags: differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

I have a relatively short question about vector fields. Let $G$ be a Lie Group, and $X$ a smooth vector field on it. If its flow is $\left\{\phi_t\right\}$ what is the corresponding flow for $-X$?

My guess was that it should be $\left\{(\phi_t(.))^{-1}\right\}$, but I don't know how to show it.

Comment: That's correct. It's also $\phi_{-t}$. The fact that $G$ is a Lie group is irrelevant. Use the chain rule a lot.